# How to configure OpenMP when using VS2019 with Qt VS Tools as the compiler?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, openmp

When i use VS2019 with Qt VS Tools,i want to use OpenMP to accelerate my calculation,but it doesn't work,i wonder how to configure it to make it work.(i choose to enable openmp in VS2019),here is my test code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for 
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        ui.textBrowser->append(QString("Hello！this is No.%1 Thread ,now i   is%2\n").arg(omp_get_thread_num()).arg(i));
    }
```

when i run it, it will throw an exception:
Exception raised at 0x00007FFEC753B548 (Qt5Gui.dll) (in qtocc_test.exe): 0xC0000005: Access conflict occurred while writing to location 0x00000274D9E616F0.

how to solve such excetion and make the openmp work?

Comment: Is `append` function threadsafe? If not, you cannot parallelize it.

Comment: it's quite true,the append function is thread unsafe,i ues qDebug() fuction,it work!